# Hide submit button before text is entered

Tags: ruby-on-rails, coffeescript

Trying to simply hide the submit button before text is entered but nothing seems to be happening. (Something in the coffeescript is wrong but i don't know what - very new to js)

My form looks like this:

```
<%= f.input :body, as: :text, input_html: { :id => "inputBody" } %>
<%= f.submit "Answer", { :id => "button" }%>
```

Coffeescript looks like this:

```
$(document).ready ->
    $("#button").hide()
    $("#button").show() if $("#inputBody").length > 0
```

Comment: Edited question but still getting same thing.

Comment: Are there any js errors on the page? https://getfirebug.com/errors Is it valid HTML? http://validator.w3.org/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I do not know CoffeScript but in JavaScript You can try something like this:

```
$(function(){
     $("#button").hide();

     $("#inputBody").keyup(function() {
         var val = $(this).val();
         if (val.length > 0) {
             $('#button').show();
         }
         else {
             $('#button').hide();
         }

     });
});
```

Comment: The key difference is `$(x).val().length` versus `$(x).length`. `$(x).length` tells you how many things matched the selector regardless of that happens to be inside the `<input>`.

Comment: Yes, but second problem is that statement (which is wrong) $("#button").show() if $("#inputBody").length > 0 is executed only once.

Comment: Right. I'm not criticizing, just trying to clarify what's going on.

Comment: Awesome, worked. One thing though - i'm looping through posts and the button only hides for the first post. Any clue why this may be?